# Wrong compiler options accepted via Batch when compiling c code using Hightec compiler

Tags: c, batch-file, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compiler c code using Hightec compiler under win7 64bit operating system. Here is my sample Batch code for compiling:

```
Root\HightecInstall\bin\ppc-vle-gcc -fno-inline -c -o sample.o sample.c
```

This is only a sample code with the compiler options "-fno-inline". After I run the batch file, I got an error saying "unknown compiler options -no-inline". But what I input is "-fno-inline". So there is a missing letter "f". I have tried with other options and the output always gave me "unknown compiler options ***" which misses one or two letter at the beginning. For example. -DDefault -> unknown -efault. I don't really understand how that could happen and how could the compiler discard the first one or two letters. Does anyone have some suggestions? Thanks.

Bo

Comment: This appears to be an error in the way the compiler parses the command line. You will need to contact the manufacturer of the compiler for assistance.

Comment: Are you sure that your batch has been saved in ASCII, not Unicode?

Comment: @Magoo I just use the default settings. Does it make difference? I found that I made a mistake. I used "ppc-vle-as -fno-inline -o sample.o sample.c" not ppc-vle-gcc. So -as gave me the error and -gcc not. But I don't know the difference between -gcc -c and the direct invocation of -as.

Comment: Yes. Batch was designed for ASCII, not unicode. Feeding instructions in unicode to `cmd` can have unexpected and unpredictable effects. This is related to the mode in which whatever editor you are using is set, nothing to do with the actual *code* you are using.